# How to save/log the output of the iex shell to get persistent command history?

Tags: shell, elixir

I just started working with Elixir and have been using the `iex` shell quite a bit.  Is it possible for me to save / log a "session" to a file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## In Erlang/OTP-20 and higher

> Since Erlang/OTP-20rc2, Shell history is supported out of the box (although initially disabled by default) through a port of [this library](https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history) to the Erlang/OTP code base. Enable the shell in these versions by setting the `shell_history` kernel environment variable to enabled with `export ERL_AFLAGS="-kernel shell_history enabled"` added to your environment variables (see [Configuration Options](https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history#configuration-options--features) to see more options).

-- https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history

### Trouble shooting

#### The history seems to be not updated (not written to the file)?

It seems that the process that is writing the history to the file does it asynchronously and it needs some time to do it before the IEx shell is closed. You need to wait a bit before you exit the shell (e.g. press `<ctrl+\>`).

---

## Pre Erlang/OTP-20:

I have found 2 ways to do it.

### 1. [Erlang History](https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history)

> erlang-history (eh) is a tiny pair of files that can be used to patch an Erlang-OTP system to add support for history in the Erlang
>   shell.
>
> The history supported is the one available through up/down arrows on
>   the keyboard.

Installation in Ubuntu Linux:

```
sudo su
cd /usr/local/src
git clone https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history.git
cd erlang-history
make install
```

Now every now started Erlang based REPL (and that is IEx) should use `erlang-history`.

---

### 2. [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap)

As an alternative you can try a more generic REPL enhancer/fixer [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) which is a "readline wrapper":

> ...a small utility that uses the GNU readline library to allow the
>   editing of keyboard input for any command.

```
rlwrap -a -A iex -S mix
```

(In case you are on Ubuntu Linux use: `sudo apt-get install rlwrap`)

It let's you add a lot more features to the REPL like e.g. the pipeto filter `rlwrap -a -z pipeto iex` that lets you pipe things to shell commands - very useful to read documentation i.e.: `iex> h Stream | less` ([more](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/RADgulL-wgk))

Know downsides:

- It breaks code completion (i.e. tab completion) in IEx

---

Why is this very useful feature - command history - not already included in Elixir/Erlang?

- https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/2945#issuecomment-66594851
- https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/1516#issuecomment-21772851

---

When using [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang) see [this](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang/issues/30#issuecomment-315366071).

Comment: Thanks for the research on this.  Using `erlang-history` on OSX seems to work great.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the advancements in this topic made in `Erlang/OTP-20`. Now its much easier to get it working.

Answer (score 10):

Not currently. You could probably write a small iex plugin to do this for you though. For example, I have the following file in `~/.iex.exs`:

```
# .iex.exs
defmodule IExHelpers do
  def reload! do
    Mix.Task.reenable "compile.elixir"
    Mix.Task.run "compile.elixir"
  end
end

iex = IExHelpers


# $ iex -S mix
# iex(2)> iex.reload!
# :noop
```

This recompiles the current project and reloads it while still inside a shell spawned with `iex -S mix`. You could probably write something to save the current shell's history to a file, and read it back in on startup, but I'm not sure where you would start with that.

Comment: How is this different from running `r ModuleName`? Is it the fact that it will recompile the whole app?