# Any readline binding support for elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to create a program which accepts user input as similar way as `iex` or `erl` does (ex. when pressing allow keys to navigate previous histories).

If the standard `IO.gets` is used as follows,

```
IO.gets "user> "
```

The console ends up with the following when up-allow is pressed.

```
user> ^[[A^[[A
```

Is there any function/library to have readline capability which can be used inside elixir code?

---

What I have investigated so far is,

- Some languages have binding support for readline libraries, but I haven't been able to find corresponding capability for elixir.
- `iex` implementation seems to delegate this capability to `erl` (/lib/iex/history.ex seems to just managing list of history), but I haven't been able to find out corresponding functionality in erlang side.
- I've tried `erl_ddll.load`, but failing to go further from the following.

on iex,

```
iex(4)> :erl_ddll.load('/usr/lib', 'libreadline')
{:error, {:open_error, -10}}
iex(5)> :erl_ddll.format_error({:open_error, -10})
'dlopen(/usr/lib/libreadline.so, 2): image not found'
```

I'm on OSX and installed libreadline through homebrew, and I can find `libreadline.dylib` in `/usr/lib`.

---

[Additional notes about purpose]

I was experimenting on the following (mal) with elixir, which is a lisp repl implemented in various languages (but not with elixir/erlang).

https://github.com/kanaka/mal

The part of the step is implementing repl with history, and some languages are using readline binding libraries if there's not native one.

[A little more update - 2015/3/22]

I was trying with NIF approach (as similar as encurses) to use readline library. I could make it somewhat work on erlang (erl), but stuck on elixir side. When reading inputs from C libraries (readline or just plain scanf), "mix run -e" or "iex" seems to behave a little weird (skips or ignores some inputs), but couldn't find out the reason. encurses seems behaving similar.

The following was my trials.

https://github.com/parroty/ereadline

https://github.com/parroty/readline

I may be going with more general approach like rlwrap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save/log the output of the iex shell to get persistent command history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426716/how-to-save-log-the-output-of-the-iex-shell-to-get-persistent-command-history)

Comment: I am not aware of any readline integration but would ncurses help with what you want to achieve? https://github.com/jzellner/encurses

Comment: Thanks for the references. I was looking for implementing history outside of iex (I've updated the background in the question). But, some of the technique might be applicable. I'll be checking on them further. I'll check ncurses too.

Comment: As far as I know the readline emulation that erlang does ( and elixir uses ) is not available on OS X. 

Even on platforms where it is available, it's actually a fairly complex process and no where near as straightforward as using libreadline usually is. 

See the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426716/how-to-save-log-the-output-of-the-iex-shell-to-get-persistent-command-history . Using rlwrap is the quick'n'dirty solution.

Comment: The rlwrap seems a nice library. I was looking for language-specific solution (as added in the question), but it seems readline is more complex than I thought. I'll try with rlwrap if I couldn't find better solution.

Comment: Ruby has a `Readline` library as part of the stdlib and it's quite easy to use. We should build something like that for Elixir.

Comment: The `rlwrap`, which can be installed with Apt, works perfectly on my Ubuntu box. With this you can edit your input using left and right arrow keys, `Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-E`, etc. You can also pull past inputs from history using up and down arrow keys.

Answer (score 16):

Disclaimer: I'm by no means an expert on the subject of jury-rigging Erlang's shell code to do one's bidding.  Corrections or clarifications to this answer are very welcome.  This was a learning process for me, too.

tl;dr: `erl` and `iex` rely on cooperation between the `edlin` module and the `tty_sl` port to implement their Readline-like features.  You can use these, too, though official documentation for doing so is lacking, to say the least.

---

Erlang's shell (upon which Elixir's is built) is quite a bit more complex than a typical REPL.  Unlike a typical REPL, it's not just looping over input and evaluating it; it's actually built much like a typical OTP application, with supervision trees all the way down.

[This article by the author of *Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good!*](http://ferd.ca/repl-a-bit-more-and-less-than-that.html) goes into further detail on the architecture of the whole Erlang shell.  To summarize:

- A platform-specific TTY driver passes user input to `user_drv`
- `user_drv` either drops into shell management mode (if it receives `^G` or `^C`) or passes input to the currently-selected `group` (there can be multiple `group`s and therefore `shell`s; when you press `^G`, you have the option of creating more `group`s, switching to existing `group`s, etc.)
- `group` works with `edlin` to put together a line of code for evaluation; once it has a line, it sends it to `shell`
- `shell` does the actual evaluation, then sends the result to `group`, which sends the result to `user_drv`
- If the `group` sending things to `user_drv` is the active group, then `user_drv` passes it on to the TTY driver (and thus to the user); else, it's muted

The part of this process that's relevant to the question is `edlin`, which is an Erlang implementation of Readline-like functionality.  `edlin` is, unfortunately, not documented particularly well as far as I can tell, but the gist of using it in Elixir (based on what I'm able to glean out of [`lib/kernel/src/group.erl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/group.erl)) is the following:

- Call `:edlin.init` in the process that's using `edlin` (this sets up a "kill buffer", in the Emacs sense of a "kill ring")
- When you're ready to read a line, call `{:more_chars,continuation,requests} = :edlin.start(prompt)`, where `prompt` is a charlist representing - you guessed it - your shell's command-line prompt
- Handle `requests`, which should be in the form of `[{:put_chars,:unicode,prompt}]`; in the Erlang shell, "handle" means "send to `user_drv` to be printed", but in your case this might be different

At this point, the looping starts.  In each iteration, you'll be calling `:edlin.edit_line(characters,continuation)` (where `characters` is a character list, i.e. from user input).  Each call will give you one of the following tuples:

- `{:done,line,rest,requests}`: `edlin` encountered a newline and is done processing your line; at this point, you can do whatever you want with `line` (your line) and `rest` (all the characters following your line)
- `{:more_chars,continuation,requests}`: `edlin` needs more characters; call `:edlin.edit_line(characters,continuation)`
- `{:blink,continuation,requests}`: I'm not 100% sure here, but I think this has to do with `edlin` highlighting characters (like when the cursor jumps to a matching `(` if you type `)`)
- `{:undefined,character,rest,continuation,requests}`: Not 100% sure here, either, but I think it has to do with handling things like command history

In all cases, `requests` will be a list of tuples corresponding to instructions for `user_drv`, usually for things like writing characters, moving the cursor, etc.

---

Next is the question of dealing with the TTY.  `user_drv.erl` does this with something called `tty_sl`, which is an Erlang port (that is, an external program designed to behave like an Erlang process) with different versions for Windows and Unix.  The basic procedure (again, Elixirified):

- Define the following (we'll need it later):

  ```
  def put_int16(num, tail) do  # we need this in a bit
    use Bitwise  # because macros
    [num |> bsr(8) |> band(255), num |> band(255) | tail]
  end
  ```
- Call `port = Port.open {:spawn,'tty_sl -c -e'}` (`-e` for "echo", `-c` for whatever "canon" means); there's a bit more error-checking in this step for `user_drv`, apparently so that it can start the older `user` instead (which - per the above-linked article - appears to be an older version of the Erlang shell)
- Spin up the `edlin`-using process described above and store it in, say, `shell` (`user_drv` does a bunch more stuff here in order to setup multiple `group`s)
- Start looping to handle requests from your `shell`

Then, in the loop:

- Receive a `request` (really a list of `request`s per above)
- Convert each `request` to something that `tty_sl` understands:

  ```
  command = case request do
    {:put_chars,:unicode,chars} ->            # OP_PUTC
      {:command, [0|:unicode.characters_to_binary(chars,:utf8)]}
    {:move_rel,count} ->                      # OP_MOVE
      {:command, [1|put_int16(count, [])]}
    {:insert_chars,:unicode,chars} ->         # OP_INSC
      {:command, [2|:unicode.characters_to_binary(chars,:utf8)]}
    {:delete_chars,count} ->                  # OP_DELC
      {:command, [3|put_int16(count, [])]}
    :beep ->                                  # OP_BEEP
      {:command, [4]}
    {:put_chars_sync,:unicode,chars,reply} -> # OP_PUTC_SYNC
      {{:command, [5|:unicode.characters_to_binary(chars,:utf8)]}, reply}
    else ->
      else
  end
  ```
- Send `command` to the TTY:

  ```
  result = case command do
    {:requests,requests} ->
      # Handle more requests
    {:command,_} = command ->
      send port, command
      :ok
    {command,reply} ->
      send port, command
      reply
    _ ->
      :ok
  end
  ```

You'll also need to receive stuff from the TTY.  In the case of `user_drv`, the TTY sends messages to the same `user_drv` process as the `group` processes.  In any case, you'll want to handle some additional messages besides the requests sent through `group` by `edlin`:

- `{port,{:data,bytes}}`: Convert `bytes` to characters and send to your shell.  Since we're in Elixir-land, we might not even need to do the conversion.
- `{port,:eof}`: Similar deal; send the `:eof` to your shell
- `{port,:ok}`: Not 100% sure about this from `user_drv`, but I believe it has to do with the `:put_chars_sync` command, given that the code in `user_drv` to handle this message deals with a `Reply` variable and that the only `tty_sl` command involving a reply is `:put_chars_sync`

The rest of the messages handled in `user_drv` pertain to the supervision tree (namely: handling process exits for both `tty_sl` and the various `group`s).

---

Of course, there's probably a much simpler answer to all of this: just use `user_drv` and create yourself a new `shell`.  This can be done (I think; not 100% sure here) with something along the lines of `user_drv_pid = :user_drv.start('tty_sl -c -e', {MyShell,:start})`.  This seems to be how `iex` works (see `IEx.CLI.start/0`).

Comment: Wow - a very detailed answer, to something that I would expect the elixir people to have already solved easily a long time ago, by default. It's as if they do not use the interactive iex.