# IEx - any way to retain commands history after restart?

Tags: elixir

I spend a lot of time in IEx lately - as a person, who relies a lot on previously entered commands, it annoys me that all my previous commands history seems to be gone after each restart of the IEx session. Is there any way to retain it?

Comment: https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history used to work with `iex` out of the box IIRC but I haven't tried recently.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22426716

Comment: Bear in mind that as much as everyone seems to forget, iex needs to work on Windows as well as *nix.  While there may be ways to get what you want I expect they will be something external to iex.